# Possible to use `log/slog` in Go v1.21 with App Engine Standard?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-go, google-app-engine-golang

I have a small project that runs on GAE Standard, and I was wondering if it was possible to avoid wrapping/importing the `cloud.google.com/go/logging` package at this point?

The goal is to some structured logging with different levels (INFO, WARN, etc.) and avoid having to do platform specific targeting, ie. running locally versus on GAE.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to run your App locally and still do logging without having to use google cloud logging package?

Comment: @NoCommandLine no, just to correctly log by log level on whichever platform it runs without wrapping to target Cloud specifically